# preventing the backspace key from deleting characters in a javafx textarea

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to prevent backspace from deleting characters in a javafx textarea. `KeyEvent.consume` should do this but it doesn't prevent the key event from happening. It does set the property of the key event and `KeyEvent.isConsumed()` gives back true after consuming the event. The backspace still gets executed. I tried other keys and there is the same effect.

This is my current fxcontroller class:

```
public class Terminal {
    @FXML
    private TextArea ta_console;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_main;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize(){
        ta_console.setText(">");
        ta_console.positionCaret(1);
    }

    public void keyStroke(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE || keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
            keyEvent.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

The `keyStroke` method gets executed by the textarea on key pressed.
Am i missing something or is `consume` bugged or somehow not functional the way the documentation says? Is there a way i can still get the desired outcome?

Comment: Not sure about javafx but in regular java you can try adding the listener to the document like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757961/2774232

Comment: @corneliu javafx' textarea does not seem to have the getDocument methode or any option to get a document from its text. Also im not sure how this would help me here.

Comment: According to this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html you can do this `myArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(myListener);`

Comment: See also [_Tab key navigation in JavaFX TextArea_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12860478/230513).

Comment: @corneliu yeah thats swing. Im using javafx.

Comment: @trashgod they use the 'consume' command there as do i. But the problem is that said command does not work as i think it should. Hence i posted this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prevent the user deleting text, that should be done with a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) instead of trying to guess which key events the control is handling internally, and in what order all those events are handled, etc. etc., for its default behavior.

It's not clear exactly what you want to achieve, but here is an example, which prevents any deletion (or replacement) of text:

```
public class Terminal {
    @FXML
    private TextArea taConsole;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize(){
        taConsole.setText(">");
        taConsole.positionCaret(1);
        taConsole.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter(change -> {
            if (change.getRangeStart() == change.getRangeEnd()) { // nothing deleted
                return change ;
            }
            // change represents a deletion of some text, veto it:
            return null ;
        });
    }

}
```

See the [Javadocs for `TextFormatter.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) for details.

Comment: this could actually work. Im trying to prevent the user from deleting anything he didn't type himself (aka the ">" i set at the beginning and everything infront)

Comment: @mr.jogurt Just check to see if the range contains that character, and veto the change if it does.,

Comment: im going to mark this as solution. Although i sadly have encountered another issue that led me to use TextFlow instead of TextArea. Still thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Unrelated to your original question, but, if you want editable multi-styled text (which would appear to be the case if you are asking about editable text and using a TextFlow), perhaps look at [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) and see if it is appropriate for you (or a JavaScript-based text editor in a WebView).